# Smaller ground okay for 240v EV charger?

Tags: wiring

Friend has 50a circuit no longer used 6/2 NM with smaller ground. He plans to extend with either same wire type or use 8awg THHN in conduit for garage section. Is it ok to use smaller awg ground ?

Answer (score 5):

### Yes, 6/2 NM will have a 10AWG ground and that's fine (for extensions, too)

A 10AWG grounding wire suffices for all circuits up to 60A in ampacity, so that's the size of ground wire you'll find in a 6AWG or 8AWG NM or UF cable, and also works fine if you're running a similarly sized circuit using individual wires in conduit.